# How to apply pandas.DataFrame.dropna on a subset of columns with inplace = True and axis = 1?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [99, None, 99], 
    'col2': [4, 5, 6], 
    'col3': [7, None, None]})

col_list = ['col1', 'col2']
df[col_list].dropna(axis=1, thresh=2, inplace = True)
```

This returns a warning and leaves the dataframe unchanged:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

The following generates no warning but still leaves the DataFrame unchanged.

```
df.loc[:,col_list].dropna(axis=1, thresh=2, inplace=True)
```

Problem:

1. From among a list of columns specified by the user, remove those columns from the dataframe which have less than 'thresh' non-null vales. Make no changes to the columns that are not in the list.
2. I need to use inplace=True to avoid making a copy of the dataframe, since it is huge

I cannot loop over the columns and apply dropna one column at a time, because pandas.Series.dropna does not have the 'thresh' argument.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough, `dropna` does not support this functionality, but there is a workaround.

```
v = df[col_list].notna().sum().le(2)    # thresh=2 
df.drop(v.index[v], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

By the way,

> I need to use inplace=True to avoid making a copy of the dataframe

I'm sorry to inform you that even with `inplace=True`, a copy is generated. The only difference is that the copy is assigned back to the original object in-place, so a new object is not returned.

Comment: Wish we had a built-in `any()` function for at least 2 items. +1 regardlessly !

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `df['col_list']` or the slicing creates a new df and `inplace=True` effects on that df and not on the original one.

You might have to use `subset` param of `dropna` and pass the column list to it.

`df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=2, subset=col_list,inplace = True)`

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I want to drop columns so I must have axis=1. And when axis=1, subset cannot be a column list; it can only be a list of the row indexes.

Comment: `df.dropna(axis=1, thresh=2, subset=col_list,inplace = True)` does not work. Did you try this?